# Book with unicorn protagonist who plays music

Tags: identification-request

It's been a long time, so my memory of the details is fuzzy. But I remember reading a book in which unicorns were the main characters; this is not a book about humans befriending unicorns in our world, but about a whole different unicorn society. The plot centered around music, something like the unicorn straying from the upper-class or 'normal' parts of society where everything was 4/4 time to the subclass/underworld and getting introduced to other time signatures like 6/8 time.

This wasn't a children's illustrated book - it was an adult book, or at least a long, young-adult chapter book (pretty sure it was adult though).

Comment: A couple of near-misses which I don't think are what you're looking for: [*Music of the Unicorn*](https://www.amazon.com/Music-Unicorn-Whole-Book-ebook/dp/B0787HZQ9V) and [*The Unicorn Sonata*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/474752.The_Unicorn_Sonata) (both involve humans befriending unicorns, rather than a fully unicorn society), and [*Birth of the Firebringer*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/58068.Birth_of_the_Firebringer) (fully unicorn society but no mention of music as far as I could tell).

Comment: I don't recognise it, but if you don't have any luck here, try at Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange where they do a lot of story identification questions and I'm often astonished the things they manage to find.